# A single word for Unpretentious

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a strong positive word that means the following:

- Unpretentious
- Doesn't try to be anything more than it is
- Unassuming

The restaurant is very _________.

I'm looking for a word that doesn't start with 'Un' and has a really positive connotation. Synonyms like 'simple' and 'genuine' don't quite seem to fit.

Comment: Perhaps "straight-forward" or "honest"?

Comment: Ordinary: with no special or distinctive features; normal.

Comment: Be aware of anthropomorphization. It can get weird. The restaurant's décor is very simple. Because otherwise it could mean the food is whatever.

Comment: You have not yet said *why* the alternatives "don't quite seem to fit." Without knowing your criteria for acceptance, anything suggested would just be a guess.

Comment: How many words is "unpretentious"?

Answer (score 4):

How about **authentic**?  [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/authentic) includes the following definition:

> : true to one's own personality, spirit, or character
>
> \\ is sincere and authentic with no pretensions

which might suit your purposes?

Answer (score 3):

Is *modest* what you're looking for? [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/modest) even says it's a synonym for 'unpretentious':

> 1 b: neither bold nor self-assertive
>
> 4 b: unpretentious

Comment: No, not quite. I'm wanting a word that feels a bit 'stronger.'

Answer (score 2):

I like humble for this use.

> Humble: Having or showing a modest or low estimate of one's own
>   importance.

Answer (score 1):

If you'll settle for a fixed phrase, you could say that it is ***[down-to-earth](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/down-to-earth)***:

> 1 : practical • *down-to-earth traveling tips*
>   2 : unpretentious • s*urprised to find the movie star so down-to-earth*
>   <sub>*definition from [merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/down-to-earth)*</sub>

Comment: Or "earthy" in a different form.

Answer (score 1):

What about **sincere**?

> ### [Sincere](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sincere)
>
> 1a : free of dissimulation : HONEST
>   b : free from adulteration : PURE
>   2 : marked by genuineness : TRUE

Answer (score 1):

The word "charming" is often used as a more positive substitute for "humble" or "small," especially in reviews, especially about things related to the hospitality industry.

Alternatively, at least in my part of California, we'd unhesitatingly describe the kind of place you're talking about as "chill."

Answer (score 0):

In the right context, "plain" is the best alternative: "plain speaking"--no frills, straight from the shoulder, as an antonym to "fancy". The usage must avoid ambiguity with the alternative meaning of "plain" as an antonym for "attractive".